# If an empty Promise is encountered within an infinite while loop, why is the while loop resolved with a pending Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

If I make a Promise that is never fulfilled:

`const nothingPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {});`

And then I `await` that Promise within an infinite `while` loop:

`async function run() { while (true) { await nothingPromise;}}`

Any `then()` function attached to the function will not run, but I don't get an infinite loop either. I get a pending Promise. In the Chrome console:

`run().then(() => console.log('then'))`
`Promise {<pending>}`

Why is a pending Promise returned? I have a feeling that it has something to do with [this part](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-loopcontinues) of the ECMAScript spec:

> The abstract operation LoopContinues takes arguments completion and labelSet and returns a Boolean. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. If completion.[[Type]] is normal, return true.
> 2. If completion.[[Type]] is not continue, return false.
> 3. If completion.[[Target]] is empty, return true.
> 4. If completion.[[Target]] is an element of labelSet, return true.
> 5. Return false.

But I don't know which completion condition corresponds to `await nothingPromise`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` sends the function it is in to sleep until:

- The promise resolves *and*
- The main event loop is free

So the `while` loop starts, the promise is `await`ed, and the function which calls `run()` receives the promise returned by `run` (which is pending because `run` is asleep) and continues.

---

Since `nothingPromise` never resolves, the `run` function never wakes up, so never completes, and never resolves the promise it returns.

---

The part of the specification you found is irrelevant since `await` sends `run` to sleep in the middle of the first iteration of the loop, so the loop never reaches completion.